# INSPIRE section not working in Geonetwork

Tags: metadata, geonetwork

I followed this tutorial: http://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/trunk/eng/users/administrator-guide/configuring-the-catalog/inspire-configuration.html?highlight=inspire

And I enabled INSPIRE in the Settings; added inspire-theme.rdf thesaurus, but inspireTheme and inspireThemeWithAc are empty. If I want to edit metadata, I can see INSPIRE keywords.

I tried installing both the .jar version and running war, but neither work.

Please help me, what to do to have working inspire directive (section is working, but looks like that lucene is returning zero keywords).

Comment: I find out that it is not working in windows, but it is working in ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was bug with path on windows sistems.

Solution is to change this line in core/src/main/java/org/fao/geonet/kernel/search/SearchManager.java

```
params.put("thesauriDir", geonetworkDataDirectory.getThesauriDir().toAbsolutePath().toString());
```

and in this file: schemas/iso19139/src/main/plugin/iso19139/index-fields/default.xsl

```
select="if ($inspire!='false') then document(concat('file:///', replace($thesauriDir, '\\', '/'), '/external/thesauri/theme/inspire-theme.rdf')) else ''"/>
```

Bugfix is here: https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/pull/1666 and is already included in newer versions of geonetwork.